# Use existing table for session in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, session, eloquent, laravel-8

I have already a session table called ci_sessions with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_sessions` (
  `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can i use this on Laravel to store my session data instead of the classic schema and store my data in a blob ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO .. did you read the Laravel doc ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#database

Comment: yes ! But i dont want to create a migration because i have already a session table

Comment: then create a model for this and use

Comment: if i do that i cant use DatabaseSessionHandler to use get/set and other methods right ?

Comment: for that you need to use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#database

Comment: Better you avoid migrate command for this

Comment: so what i need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The default session table name provided by the framework is 'sessions', which is hardcoded in the [database.stub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Session/Console/stubs/database.stub#L16). As long as you create the session table via `php artisan session:table; php artisan migrate`, it's typically unchangeable.

However, you could use the table you like by modifying `config/session.php` like this.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'ci_sessions',
```